# Fundamental vector field definition

Tags: lie-groups, vector-fields, principal-bundles

Let $P$ be a principal $G$ bundle, where $G$ denotes a Lie group.

Then this action defines a map $\sigma : \mathfrak{g} \to TP$ from the Lie algebra of $G$ to the vector fields on $P$, given by:
$$\sigma_p(X) =\frac{d}{dt}(p \cdot e^{tX}),$$
where $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ and $p \in P$.

I'm trying to understand how this works. From my understanding if the representation of the group is a matrix representation, so some element of $Aut(M)$, then we can explicitly perform the derivative to get
$$\sigma_p(X) =p \cdot X,$$
where now we have the induced Lie algebra acting on the manifold.

I don't see how this defines a vector field? Is it because, say we take any element $p \in P$ to be 2-dimensional, and $X$ a 2-dimensional representation, then $p \cdot X$ will be a 2-dimensional vector, say $p \cdot X=(a_1, a_2)$ and we are viewing this as a vector of the form $a_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + a_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$?

Also, do you know of any good notes for when we are not in a matrix representation?

Comment: Given the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt}= Xy$, for constant X, we have $\frac{dy}{y}= Xdt$ and, integrating, $ln(y)= Xt+ c$ which we can write as $y= Ce^{Xt}$ where $C= e^c$.   That is the sense in which a member of the Lie Algebra, X, leads to the vector field, y(t).

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm trying to understand how this works. From my understanding if the representation of the group is a matrix representation, so some element of Aut(M), then we can explicitly perform the derivative ..."

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow P$ defined by $f(t)=p.e^{tX}$. It is a differentiable map, and its differential $df:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow TP$, $\sigma_p(X)=df(1)$.